# Factorize a column of strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

As the question says, I have a data frame `df_original` which is quite large but looks like:

```
        ID    Count   Column 2   Column 3  Column 4
RowX    1      234.     255.       yes.      452
RowY    1      123.     135.       no.       342
RowW    1      234.     235.       yes.      645
RowJ    1      123.     115.       no.       342
RowA    1      234.     285.       yes.      233
RowR    1      123.     165.       no.       342
RowX    2      234.     255.       yes.      234
RowY    2      123.     135.       yes.      342
RowW    2      234.     235.       yes.      233
RowJ    2      123.     115.       yes.      342
RowA    2      234.     285.       yes.      312
RowR    2      123.     165.       no.       342
.
.
.
RowX    1233   234.     255.       yes.      133
RowY    1233   123.     135.       no.       342
RowW    1233   234.     235.       no.       253
RowJ    1233   123.     115.       yes.      342
RowA    1233   234.     285.       yes.      645
RowR    1233   123.     165.       no.       342
```

I am trying to get rid of the text data and replace it with a predefined numerical equivalent. For example, in this case, I'd like to replace `Column3`'s `yes` or `no` values with `1` or `0` respectively. Is there a way to do this without me having to manually go in and alter the values?

Comment: For-loop and if-else statement and using the replace method or regex

Comment: something like     `df['Column 3']=df['Column 3'].replace({'yes.':1,'no.':0})` ?

Comment: wouldn't `df_original.Column3 = df_original.Column3.apply(lambda x : int(x == 'yes.'))` suffice ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
series

RowX    yes
RowY     no
RowW    yes
RowJ     no
RowA    yes
RowR     no
RowX    yes
RowY    yes
RowW    yes
RowJ    yes
RowA    yes
RowR     no
Name: Column 3, dtype: object
```

#### `pd.factorize`

```
1 - series.factorize()[0]
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

---

#### `np.where`

```
np.where(series == 'yes', 1, 0)
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

---

#### `pd.Categorical`/`astype('category')`

```
pd.Categorical(series).codes
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int8)
```

```
series.astype('category').cat.codes

RowX    1
RowY    0
RowW    1
RowJ    0
RowA    1
RowR    0
RowX    1
RowY    1
RowW    1
RowJ    1
RowA    1
RowR    0
dtype: int8
```

---

#### `pd.Series.replace`

```
series.replace({'yes' : 1, 'no' : 0})
 
RowX    1
RowY    0
RowW    1
RowJ    0
RowA    1
RowR    0
RowX    1
RowY    1
RowW    1
RowJ    1
RowA    1
RowR    0
Name: Column 3, dtype: int64
```

A fun, generalised version of the above:

```
series.replace({r'^(?!yes).*$' : 0}, regex=True).astype(bool).astype(int)

RowX    1
RowY    0
RowW    1
RowJ    0
RowA    1
RowR    0
RowX    1
RowY    1
RowW    1
RowJ    1
RowA    1
RowR    0
Name: Column 3, dtype: int64
```

Anything that is not `"yes"` is `0`.

Comment: I would like make this site only have your neat answer ~ :-)